# rearrangement of IN clause output

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a `IN` clause query in which I pass this ID'S `(10,19,23,24,28,33,45,46,1,4,7,8,12,16,18,22,29)`

**My query is,** 
 **`SELECT`post_jobs`.`id`FROM`post_jobs`WHERE`id`IN(10,19,23,24,28,33,45,46,1,4,7,8,12,16,18,22,29)`** 
It execute correctly and returns result first id likes 1 then 4 then 7 and so on...that is ascending order

My Need is to get first result of id 10 then 19 then 23 as the order of ID that I passed is there any way to get such type of result in output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT post_jobs.id FROM post_jobs WHERE id 
IN(10,19,23,24,28,33,45,46,1,4,7,8,12,16,18,22,29) ORDER BY 
FIELD(id,10,19,23,24,28,33,45,46,1,4,7,8,12,16,18,22,29);
```

In Codeigniter

```
$this->db->_protect_identifiers = FALSE; 
$this->db->select('id'); 
$this->db->where_in('id',array(10,19,23,24,28,33,45,46,1,4,7,8,12,16,18,22,29));
$this->db->order_by('FIELD(id, 10,19,23,24,28,33,45,46,1,4,7,8,12,16,18,22,29)'); 
$this->db->get('post_jobs');
```

If you are using codeigniter 3 then write or remove the line of protect_identifiers

```
$this->db->protect_identifiers(False);
```

Comment: How can I add field using codeigniter    $wherecon="id IN(".$jobs_id.")"; 
  $this->db->where($wherecon);
  $this->db->limit($per_page,$offset);
  $this->db->select("post_jobs.id");
  $query=$this->db->get('post_jobs');
  if($query->num_rows()>0)
   return $query->result();
  else
   return FALSE;

Comment: May be this works 
$where = "FIELD(id, 10,19,23,24,28,33,45,46,1,4,7,8,12,16,18,22,29)";  
$this->db->where( $where );

Comment: incorrect parameter count in the call to native function FIND_IN_SET

Comment: SELECT `id` FROM `post_jobs` WHERE `post_jobs`.`status` = 1 AND `id` IN ('1','4','7','8','9','10','12','16','18','19','22','23','24','28','29','33','38','39','43','44','45','46') ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET ( `id`,'1','4','7','8','9','10','12','16','18','19','22','23','24','28','29','33','38','39','43','44','45','46')

Comment: Please see my edited answer.

Comment: Getting error Fatal error: Cannot access protected property CI_DB_mysqli_driver::$_protect_identifiers in

Comment: Try $this->db->protect_identifiers(False); if you are using In codeigniter 3

Comment: I comment this line and it works $this->db->_protect_identifiers = FALSE; is there any problem if I comment it ?

Comment: No its fine if you are using version 3

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
SELECT post_jobs.id FROM post_jobs WHERE post_jobs.id 
IN(10,19,23,24,28,33,45,46,1,4,7,8,12,16,18,22,29) ORDER BY 
FIND_IN_SET(post_jobs.id,10,19,23,24,28,33,45,46,1,4,7,8,12,16,18,22,29);
```

Comment: How can I add field using codeigniter    $wherecon="id IN(".$jobs_id.")"; 
  $this->db->where($wherecon);
  $this->db->limit($per_page,$offset);
  $this->db->select("post_jobs.id");
  $query=$this->db->get('post_jobs');
  if($query->num_rows()>0)
   return $query->result();
  else
   return FALSE;

Comment: `$query = $this->db->query("Your Core Query",false);` or try `$query = $this->db->query("Your Core Query");` might be useful to you.

Comment: please accept the answer if it is useful for you